# Is possible to use textures with Quartz 2D instead of Open GL?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics

My App is a drawing finger. I use CGContext, quadratic curves, pattern images, rotation... Specifically:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

[code...]

```
     CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
```

[code...]

```
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, kSize, kSize), patternImage.CGImage);
```

[code...]

```
     CGPatternRef strokePattern = CGPatternCreate(NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, kSize, kSize),
                                              CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle),
                                              kSize,
                                              kSize,
                                              kCGPatternTilingNoDistortion,
                                              true,
                                              &kPatternCallbacks);

}
```

For more details: [iphone: Apply a texture to CGContextStrokePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635332/iphone-apply-a-texture-to-cgcontextstrokepath)

How can I do for quality results like: [ios - Drawing Brush from finger toches moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386124/ios-drawing-brush-from-finger-toches-moves)

**And NOT, this result so horrible?**

[image: texture pattern image]

The target:

[image: Water colour texture]

Or something like (Drawing With Carl App from Tayasui developer):

[image: Draw Carl App]

[image: Drawing With Carl App]

Or this (Sketches from Tayasui developer):

[image: Sketches App]

Comment: what do you want - a thinner line or what?

Comment: I want a result like the textures of Sketches (or Paper by 53) Apps. My texture image always fills the stroke path. And it seems an adding circles. And Does not seem the stroke from crayon, watercolor brush, graphite pencil, or whatever.

Comment: start by experimenting with opacity and blend mode

Comment: also a texture in open GL isn't necessarily the same as a texture, a patterned paint

Comment: you could use gradient or shading?

Comment: have a look at this it's interesting http://harrisonjackson.us/category/mobile/

Comment: It is important to clarify some things: **I tested OPACITY and all kinds of BLEND MODES.**

Comment: It is important to clarify some things: **I tested OPACITY and all kinds of BLEND MODES.** That it is not the problem. I tested **SHADOWS** (CGContextSetShadowWithColor) and the same: **it is not the key.** With CGContextSetShadowWithColor I achieved a texture similar to graffiti spray (it is OK, but it is not the texture like colored wax, charcoal, or graphite pencil) And the last: **Sketches or 53 are apps made it with Open GL**, more powerful but more complicated (a lot more).

Comment: I do not understand the relation with this question: http://harrisonjackson.us/category/mobile/

Comment: The closest to the solution to my problem it is the Apple demo GLPaint.xcodeproj. But I made the mistake of choosing this option: http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit

Comment: I have built too much, using Quartz 2D instead of Open GL. I think it is too late to start again. It is also true that for someone who has not worked with OpenGL is complicated. OpenGL is not as friendly as Quartz 2D.